# how to install windows phone 8.1 app to device in linux?

Tags: linux, deployment, windows-phone-8.1, installation

I have a problem as the title. I have an app .appxbundle and I want to deploy it to device from linux PC? Are there any tools can do that? My device is windows phone 8.1. Thank for help!

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this. You have to use Windows (a virtual machine should be fine).